Bought bitcoins in 2014/2015 thru a website similar to Facebook
In 2014/2015 there was a website similar to Facebook we posted articles on and communicated on, but different that mainly many Eastern Indians used where we traded bitcoins using Bitzfunda, Payza or a company to buy through to trade with one another. I purchased quite a few times when I got paid. The website no longer was in use in 2017 when I went back to post and find where our big coins were placed. I never thought the website would vanish. It just disappeared.
Cher’ie Walker
